# Closed one-syllable words -- patach or kamatz?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading

For closed one-syllable Hebrew words that take only a patach or kamatz (יָ֥ד, עַ֖ל,  רַ֛ק, etc.), is there any rhyme or reason as to which ones can only take one and which the other, or is it just something to be memorized?

Note: I am excluding verbs (בָא֮), and am not asking about shifts in vowelization in the same word from kamatz to patach (due, e.g., to construct form) or from patach to kamatz (due, e.g., to pausal form).

Comment: Isn’t this the same rule as multisyllabic nouns - i.e., if they take an esnachta/sof passuk the patach switches to a kamatz?

Comment: Are you asking because you pronounce the two vowels differently and that could invalidate a Torah reading if you're not careful so you want some mnemonic assistance? Also, I hope my edit is what you intended. I was a bit confused.

Comment: DonielF, I explicitly said that was not my question.

Comment: WAF, yes I pronounce them differently.

Comment: @user432944 Make sure to stick the @ sign before my name if you want to make sure I see your response. I understand that’s not your question, which is why I’m asking why you think it’s different in that you limit your question.

Comment: @DonielF I'm not sure what you mean. The word יָ֥ד takes a kamatz (unless it is in the construct state). The word עַ֖ל takes a patach (unless it is pausal, which I don't think is possible for the prepositional form of the word). I'm asking why that is the case.

Comment: @user432944 1. You should [edit] all that into the question, since you clearly know more than I and probably most MY users do on the subject. 2. Why do you differentiate verbs out, but assume nouns and prepositions follow the same rules?

Comment: הנה משמני הארץ יהיה מושבך ומטל השמים מעל

Comment: @Heshy, I don't think עַ֖ל is being used as the preposition "on" there...

Comment: Here are nouns with patakh: עם, שר, הר, פר, כף, בת and adjectives with qamas: חם, תם and adverbs: אז, שם. 
There are several reasons to explain these forms. For example: forms deriving from originally qal (short vowel) nouns take a qamas, and ones coming from qall (or qatl, with assimilation) (short vowels) tend to have patakh (but before ם we usually have qamas).

Comment: Words like כף and בת are phonemically /kapp/ and /bitt/.  In their nominal form, the doubling of the 2nd consonant drops, but the underlying vowel remains "short" i.e., patah and not qamatz.  That said, the doubling reappears in other forms e.g., kappi and bitti for 1st person singular possessive. (Ashkenazim don't pronounce the doubling.)

The patah for "prepositions" like עַ֖ל and רַ֛ק is a different phenomenon.  In such cases, the word "goes with" the succeeding word and so the vowel is reduced from a short vowel.  (It's similar to the construct/semikhuth form for nouns ending in qamatz.)